# How do I clear hard disk space after a Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

**Short version:**

Where on a Windows 10 box are the delete-able dump files left from the installation of VS 2017 and VS 2019? They are eating up too much space on my hard drive and I want to delete them.

**Longer version:**

I had VS 2019 for a couple of months. Then I wanted to set up the ASP.NET MVC 5.2.6 source code on my machine, and the ASP.NET team said that that could run only on VS2017, so I did a side-by-side installation of VS2017.

Still, the ASP.NET MVC build process did not pass. So, I was advised to download and install VS 2017 BuildTools as a separate download and install. I did.

In all this while, these two new installs have taken up more than 14 GB of my hard disk space even though the install process said it would take less than 6 GB in total.

My guess is that the dump files from which the installation was done are there somewhere in my computer and they can be deleted. Only I don't know where.

The earlier installs used to create their own weird folders in the system root that were named with GUID's, and these could be deleted. I remember having had this same problem a few years ago and I was advised that it was okay to delete those GUID named folders.

But these new installs do not leave such folders. Where are the files that I can delete?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is too obvious a suggestion and doesn't work in this situation, but did you try Disk Cleanup and it did nothing?  On my Win 10 machine when I do a Properties on the c: drive, there is a Disk Cleanup button.

Comment: Sorry I just did a Disk Cleanup and it's unlikely it would help your problem,   It's shows you what it can cleanup and I didn't see anything that was large downloads from a previous install and not much install related at all.